# logging works wrong with pyinstaller application: calling module and function are set to 'logging' and 'debug'

Tags: python, logging, pyinstaller

I have python application which uses module 'logging' and I package it with pysintaller.

I am using below format string:

```
%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(threadName)s:%(module)s.%(funcName)s()] %(message)s
```

If I run application as python script, it works fine, '%(module)s.%(funcName)s' gets replaced with actual values of calling module and function:

```
2014-06-19 18:46:10,373 DEBUG [MainThread:subcommands.exec_cmd()] Executing `service iptables stop` on server centos6root
2014-06-19 18:46:10,373 DEBUG [MainThread:ssh._connect()] Trying to connect to server centos6root
2014-06-19 18:46:10,945 DEBUG [MainThread:ssh._connect()] Established connection with root@192.168.122.57:22
2014-06-19 18:46:11,533 DEBUG [MainThread:subcommands.exec_cmd()] exitstatus = 0
2014-06-19 18:46:11,648 DEBUG [MainThread:ssh.cleanup()] Closed connection to server centos6root
2014-06-19 18:46:11,649 DEBUG [MainThread:hwswa2.main()] Application finished
```

However, if I package my application with pyinstaller, it now substitutes 'logging.debug' for '%(module)s.%(funcName)s':

```
2014-06-19 19:04:05,577 DEBUG [MainThread:logging.debug()] Executing `echo hello` on server centos6root
2014-06-19 19:04:05,577 DEBUG [MainThread:logging.debug()] Trying to connect to server centos6root
2014-06-19 19:04:06,293 DEBUG [MainThread:logging.debug()] Established connection with root@192.168.122.57:22
2014-06-19 19:04:06,705 DEBUG [MainThread:logging.debug()] exitstatus = 0
2014-06-19 19:04:06,707 DEBUG [MainThread:logging.debug()] Closed connection to server centos6root
2014-06-19 19:04:06,707 DEBUG [MainThread:logging.debug()] Application finished
```

What can be the reason and how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree

Answer (score 1):

I was using direct calls to `logging.info()`, `logging.debug()` etc.

The problem was solved by using separate loggers for each module

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and calling `logger.info()`, `logger.debug()` etc.